# Resolving an error in encryption program, where/how to declare variable when null can't be used

Tags: java, parsing, encryption

I'd appreciate any help with this problem i'm encountering. On line 27 of code below I'm getting an error that location cannot be resolved to a variable. *( BufferedReader br = Parse.parseLocation(location, key);)*
Initialising to null does not work in my program (I don't get the result I want) and I'm stumped trying to figure out how to resolve this. Where and how should it be declared properly?
I've also pasted the Parse file below for additional clarity.
Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Enter Cipher Key:");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String key = s.nextLine();


   System.out.println("Enter a text file or URL to encrypt:");
    System.out.flush();
    Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = r.nextLine();
    File f = new File(filename);

    r.close();
    s.close();

    try{
    Porta cipher = new Porta(key);

    cipher.ensureCapacity((int)f.length());       
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("out.txt");
    BufferedReader br = Parse.parseLocation(location, key);
    String line = null;


       while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String encrypted = cipher.encrypt(line.toUpperCase());
            fw.write(encrypted + "\n" );

        }

        br.close();
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Yikes! Something nasty happened");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And the aforementioned parse file as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Parse {

private static BufferedReader br;
private static final String FORM = "http://"; //Identify a URL header   
public static BufferedReader parseLocation(String location, String key) 
{       
    try{
        if(location.startsWith(FORM)){
            URL url = new URL(location);    
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream())); 
            System.out.println("\nURL successfully read");
        }

        else{ //If input is a file
            File file = new File(location); //New instance of URL
            if(file.exists()){
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file))); 
            }
            System.out.println("\nFile successfully read");
        }
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Prints the stack trace of the Exception to System.err.
    }

    return br; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = Parse.parseLocation(location, key);
```

Here you are passing `location` as parameter but `location` variable has not been declared.

You need to declare it as a global variable, or as local variable before calling `Parse.parseLocation(...)`. Something like this

```
String location = "http://http://stackoverflow.com";
BufferedReader br = Parse.parseLocation(location, key);
```